# Подключение WebMoney на своем сайте ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, md5, webmoney, sha256

Подключаю кнопку оплаты WebMoney на своем сайте.
На сайте создано 3 страницы. Результат платежа принимаю в хендлере PayResult.ashx

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string test = context.Request.Url.ToString();

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
            {
                string postedData = reader.ReadToEnd();

                DataHelper.Payment(postedData);
            }

            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Ok");
        }
```

Метод Payment(string postedData)

```
public static void Payment(string postedData)
        {
            //WebMoney

            try
            {
                string LMI_PAYEE_PURSE = string.Empty;
                string LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT = string.Empty;
                string LMI_PAYMENT_NO = string.Empty;
                string LMI_MODE = string.Empty;
                string LMI_SYS_INVS_NO = string.Empty;
                string LMI_SYS_TRANS_NO = string.Empty;
                string LMI_SYS_TRANS_DATE = string.Empty;
                string LMI_SECRET_KEY = string.Empty;
                string LMI_PAYER_PURSE = string.Empty;
                string LMI_PAYER_WM = string.Empty;
                string LMI_HASH = string.Empty;

                foreach (var item in postedData.Split(new[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    var tokens = item.Split(new[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    if (tokens.Length < 2)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var paramName = tokens[0];
                    var paramValue = tokens[1];

                    switch (paramName)
                    {
                        case "LMI_PAYEE_PURSE":
                            LMI_PAYEE_PURSE = paramValue;
                            break;
                        case "LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT":
                            LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT = paramValue;
                            break;
                        case "LMI_PAYMENT_NO":
                            LMI_PAYMENT_NO = paramValue;
                            break;
                        case "LMI_MODE":
                            LMI_MODE = paramValue;
                            break;
                        case "LMI_SYS_INVS_NO":
                            LMI_SYS_INVS_NO = paramValue;
                            break;
                        case "LMI_SYS_TRANS_NO":
                            LMI_SYS_TRANS_NO = paramValue;
                            break;
                        case "LMI_SYS_TRANS_DATE":
                            LMI_SYS_TRANS_DATE = paramValue;
                            break;
                        case "LMI_SECRET_KEY":
                            LMI_SECRET_KEY = paramValue;
                            break;
                        case "LMI_PAYER_PURSE":
                            LMI_PAYER_PURSE = paramValue;
                            break;
                        case "LMI_PAYER_WM":
                            LMI_PAYER_WM = paramValue;
                            break;
                        case "LMI_HASH":
                            LMI_HASH = paramValue;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

                StringBuilder toHash = new StringBuilder();
                toHash.Append(LMI_PAYEE_PURSE);
                toHash.Append(LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT);
                toHash.Append(LMI_PAYMENT_NO);
                toHash.Append(LMI_MODE);
                toHash.Append(LMI_SYS_INVS_NO);
                toHash.Append(LMI_SYS_TRANS_NO);
                toHash.Append(LMI_SYS_TRANS_DATE);
                toHash.Append(LMI_SECRET_KEY);
                toHash.Append(LMI_PAYER_PURSE);
                toHash.Append(LMI_PAYER_WM);
                MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
                byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(toHash.ToString()));
                StringBuilder hashStr = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (byte b in hash)
                    hashStr.Append(b.ToString("x2"));

                if (string.Compare(LMI_HASH, hashStr.ToString(), true) != 0)
                {
                    int bbb = 100;
                }
}
}
```

Проблема в том, что хеш, который прилетает от WebMoney и хеш, который генерится методом md5.ComputeHash мало того что разные по значению, но совершенно разные по длине.

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Приведите пример данных, которые вы хешируете (саму склееную строку), полученный хэш, и ожидаемый хэш. [Судя по документации](https://wiki.webmoney.ru/projects/webmoney/wiki/Web_Merchant_Interface#14), там на выбор может быть md5, sha256 или sign. Может у вас просто не md5 включён?

Comment: Действительно проблема была в том, что на странице настройки кошелька https://merchant.webmoney.ru/conf/purses.asp выбирая MD5 не сохранялись настройки и остаётся шифрование SHA256. Вопрос решился! WebMoney не работает с MD5, хотя указывает возможность его выбрать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё получилось.
Дату только пришлось правильно распознать.

```
//WebMoney

try
{
    string LMI_PAYEE_PURSE = string.Empty;
    string LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT = string.Empty;
    string LMI_PAYMENT_NO = string.Empty;
    string LMI_MODE = string.Empty;
    string LMI_SYS_INVS_NO = string.Empty;
    string LMI_SYS_TRANS_NO = string.Empty;
    string LMI_SYS_TRANS_DATE = string.Empty;
    string LMI_SECRET_KEY = string.Empty;
    string LMI_PAYER_PURSE = string.Empty;
    string LMI_PAYER_WM = string.Empty;
    string LMI_HASH = string.Empty;

    foreach (var item in postedData.Split(new[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        var tokens = item.Split(new[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (tokens.Length < 2)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var paramName = tokens[0];
        var paramValue = tokens[1];

        switch (paramName)
        {
            case "LMI_PAYEE_PURSE":
                LMI_PAYEE_PURSE = paramValue;
                break;
            case "LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT":
                LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT = paramValue;
                break;
            case "LMI_PAYMENT_NO":
                LMI_PAYMENT_NO = paramValue;
                break;
            case "LMI_MODE":
                LMI_MODE = paramValue;
                break;
            case "LMI_SYS_INVS_NO":
                LMI_SYS_INVS_NO = paramValue;
                break;
            case "LMI_SYS_TRANS_NO":
                LMI_SYS_TRANS_NO = paramValue;
                break;
            case "LMI_SYS_TRANS_DATE":
                LMI_SYS_TRANS_DATE = paramValue;
                LMI_SYS_TRANS_DATE = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(LMI_SYS_TRANS_DATE);
                break;
            case "LMI_SECRET_KEY":
                LMI_SECRET_KEY = paramValue;
                break;
            case "LMI_PAYER_PURSE":
                LMI_PAYER_PURSE = paramValue;
                break;
            case "LMI_PAYER_WM":
                LMI_PAYER_WM = paramValue;
                break;
            case "LMI_HASH":
                LMI_HASH = paramValue;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    StringBuilder toHash = new StringBuilder();
    toHash.Append(LMI_PAYEE_PURSE);
    toHash.Append(LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT);
    toHash.Append(LMI_PAYMENT_NO);
    toHash.Append(LMI_MODE);
    toHash.Append(LMI_SYS_INVS_NO);
    toHash.Append(LMI_SYS_TRANS_NO);
    toHash.Append(LMI_SYS_TRANS_DATE);
    toHash.Append(LMI_SECRET_KEY);
    toHash.Append(LMI_PAYER_PURSE);
    toHash.Append(LMI_PAYER_WM);

    string hashStr = CryptHelper.Sha256(toHash.ToString());

    if (string.Compare(LMI_HASH, hashStr, true) == 0)
    {
        bool goodResult = true;
        //...
    }



}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    AddEventString(string.Format("Exception: {0}", ex.Message));
}
```

Получение хеша sha256:

```
public static string Sha256(string value)
{
    SHA256Managed crypt = new SHA256Managed();
    string hash = String.Empty;
    byte[] crypto = crypt.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(value));
    foreach (byte theByte in crypto)
    {
        hash += theByte.ToString("x2");
    }
    return hash;
}
```